# Why does Rasbian report the Cortex-A72 CPU of the Raspberry 4 as ARMv7?

Tags: arm

I run `lscpu` on a Raspberry Pi 4:

```
Architecture:        armv7l
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
Vendor ID:           ARM
Model:               3
Model name:          Cortex-A72
Stepping:            r0p3
CPU max MHz:         1500.0000
CPU min MHz:         600.0000
BogoMIPS:            108.00
Flags:               half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
```

It says that it is a ARMv7 architecture, although Wikipedia says it should be a ARMv8 architecture.

What is the reason for this mismatch?

Comment: you can have the linux kernel in 64bit of course, then it is reported as `aarch64`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36009487/raspberry-pi-3-cpuinfo-armv7).

Till the Pi goes 64bit O/S I guess it will only report v7.

Comment: So `lscpu` does not tell anything about the CPU but just the kernel?

Comment: Yea, the architcture report is wrong there. Try `cat /proc/cpuinfo` to get the real hardware. "BCM2835" is the correct CPU for a Raspberry Pi 4.

Comment: @PMF **ALL** Pi models report BCM2835 so this is meaningless!

Comment: @Milliways: Oh... Good catch. Didn't notice that 2835 is quite wrong for the Pi4.